# HybridAuth error with facebook login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

i am using HybridAuth for my sites login.
it works with every thing but facebook.
when i use "sign-in-with-facebook", it returens an error:

```
Authentication error!

Authentication failed. The user has canceled the authentication or the provider refused the connection.

Original error message: Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.
```

i have disabled sandbox mode.
can anyone help me to understand this, and what shoud i do for this?

i clicked the "sign-in-with-facebook" button after i log-out from facebook,
then it return error like below, insted of appearing facebook login-page.

```
Warning
The website directing you here was not a Facebook page. If you entered your Facebook login information on the previous site, you will need to reset your password.
Email:  
To learn more about staying safe on the internet, visit our Security Page. You can also check out the phishing Wikipedia article.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was happend due to my hosting provider (free hosting provider) did not allow HybridAuth to communicate with facebook. but wen i moved to paid hosting, problem solved!.

hope this will help for someone.

Comment: Hi, how did you came to know that your hosting provider is not allowing HybridAuth to communicate with Facebook ?
I'm facing the same issue, so how i can check ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the base_facebook.php file in apps\third_party\hybridauth\Hybrid\thirdparty\Facebook folder if you are using codeigniter

Find this line :
$response_params = **parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);**

AND Replace it with : 
$response_params = **json_decode($access_token_response, true);**

Hope your code will work.